# Making a new array from values of 4 different arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have 4 different arrays

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
arr3 = ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4"];
arr4 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"];
```

I need to create a new array as below:

```
new_array = ["a", "1", "a1", "aa"];
```

I didn't mean to address only the first value what I meant is to create new array with all values... sorry if I confused you all..

**Solution**

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr3 = ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4"];
var arr4 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"];
var new_array =[];
i=0;
$.each(arr1, function(i, item){
    new_array.push([arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]]);
    i++;
 });

console.log(new_array);
```

Comment: What is the question. You have given the solution yourself in the last line?

Comment: Do you have an attempt at creating a solution that you can share? What results or outcome did it give you?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i tried different ways but got confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_array = [ arr1[0],arr2[0],arr3[0],arr4[0] ]
```

Comment: Got the idea using ur method... just need $.each to get all values

Comment: jquery is not necessary at all! You could use foreach but also a normal loop or in this case just access the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr3 = ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4"];
var arr4 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"];

var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].map(a => a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more, just for diversity... :)

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr3 = ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4"];
var arr4 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"];

var new_arr = arr1.concat(arr2,arr3,arr4).filter(function(val,i) {
return i%4==0;
});

console.log(new_arr);
```